# Drupal: how to add multilingual content to page templates?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I sometimes add to page.tpl.php file, some text, but I would like to make it multilingual.

I've tried to use t('blabla') function, but the text just disappears. I guess this function is used in forms only and not for theme templates.

How can I make it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use t() everywhere, but don't forget to print the return value. Try this:

```
<?php print t('Translatable text in English'); ?>
```

Visit the page at least once and then head over to the translations admin page to enter the translation for your English text.